# What is the alternative of [clearable] in ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular7, angular-ngselect

I do not want to use the `[clearable]` in `ng-select` for leakage of my space. Instead of `[clearable]` I want to use only `[clearOnBackspace]` but when I write  `[clearable] = "false"` and `[clearOnBackspace] = "true"` it does not work.

```
enter code here

    <ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
               [clearable]="false"
               [clearOnBackspace] = "true"
               [excludeGroupsFromDefaultSelection] = "true">
    </ng-select>
```

Comment: if 'clearable' property is set to false, and clearOnBackspace is set to true, user can remove single item using backspace button.

if (this.filterValue || (!multiple && !this.clearable) || !this.clearOnBackspace || !this.hasValue) {

template example:

<ng-select>
(add)=...
(remove)=...
[multiple]="true"
[clearable]="false"
[clearOnBackspace]="true"
</ng-select>

you can hide clear button simply by css

Comment: use `[clearable]="true"` it will be cleared on backspace only

Comment: The user selects only a single value. So [multiple]="true" not needed. Yap I can remove the cross button using CSS but I want to handle it by JavaScript.

Comment: @Just Code if i make [clearable]="true" it also shows the cross icon. I do not allow it for my space lackage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `[clearable]="false"` it will disallow to clear the selection.

you can use css to hide the close icon. like this

```
.ng-clear-wrapper{
  display: none;
}
```

and keep `ng-select` as it is

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-oqjqhh?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
<ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
               [clearable]="true"
               [clearOnBackspace] = "true"
               [excludeGroupsFromDefaultSelection] = "true">
```

infact you do not need `[clearOnBackspace] = "true"`

Comment: @Sabbir Why not css?